# Accessing an element of an Array in OpenCV

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

I am trying to get the value of an element in an array in order to use it in an `if` statement but unfortunately the following code is not working for me. The `cout` of `comp` is not matching the first element of the array C. I'm new to OpenCV so any help is appreciated.

```
Mat A = (Mat_<double>(2,1) << u, v); 
Mat B = (Mat_<double>(2,6) << -1/Z,  0 ,  x/Z , x*y , -(x*x+1),y,                                                       
                               0 ,-1/Z,  y/Z ,y*y+1,   -x*y  ,-x);
Mat pinvB = B.inv(DECOMP_SVD);
Mat C=pinvB*A; // 6x1 Array

float comp = C.at<float>(0,0);
cout << "comp " << comp << endl; //This value does not match C[0,0]
cout << "C " << C << endl;

if (comp < 0.0001){
   //process
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `double comp = C.at<double>(0,0);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Mat_<double>` instances internally store `double`s. When you do this:

```
float comp = C.at<float>(0,0);
```

you are trying to use some of the bits that form a double, and interpret them as a `float`. Floating point representation means that half of the bits of a `double` don't translate into a meaningful `float` (assuming a platform where float has half the size of a double, which is quite common). So, call `C.at<double>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you use the template version of `cv::Mat_<_Tp>`, you can access pixel value by `Mat_<_Tp>::operator ()(int y, int x)`

```
cv::Mat_<double> M(3, 3);
for (int i = 0;i < 3; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0;j < 3; ++j) {
    std::cout<<M(i, j)<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

so that later if you change the template argument from double to float, you don't need to modify each `at()`.